# What is the idiomatic way to transform an Option<impl Iterator> into an impl Iterator?

Tags: rust, iterator

I want to create a utility function which reads the contents of a directory, and returns an iterator to the file names contained within, excluding a specified filename.

So the signature should be like this:

```
fn dir_contents_excluding<'a>(dir: &Path, excluding: &str) -> impl Iterator<Item = &'a str>
```

and for instance if I have a directory like this:

```
/my_dir
  /foo.txt
  /bar.txt
  /baz.txt
```

And I call the function like so:

```
for file in dir_contents_excluding("./my_dir", "bar.txt") {
    println!(file);
}
```

The console output should be:

```
foo.txt
baz.txt
```

So far I have an implementation which looks like this:

```
use fs;
fn dir_contents_excluding<'a>(dir: &Path, excluding: &str) -> impl Iterator<Item = &'a str> {
    let read_dir = fs::read_dir(dir);

    match read_dir {
        // Here I transform the read_dir results 
        // into filenames
        Ok(read_dir) => read_dir.filter_map(...),
        Err(_) => // ?? not sure what to do here
    }
}
```

So in the case that `fs::read_dir` returns an error, I would like to return an empty iterator, so that I don't have to handle the error case at the call site.

What would be the best way to achieve this?

Comment: Nit: you cannot implement your function this way. You have to return owned `String` or `PathBuf`s.

Comment: Why not?  I mean what prevents this?

Comment: Because `std::fs::read_dir()` returns owned `PathBuf`s, and you cannot drop them.

Comment: Where would they be dropped?

Comment: Try to write it, even without error handling.

Comment: Put another way: given the `&str` in the iterator item is a refererence, what is it referring to, where is it held in memory and for how long?

Comment: But, to answer your actual question, you probably want: `opt.into_iter().flatten()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to your question is: using `.into_iter().flatten()`. `Option` itself is iterable, so `into_iter()` converts `Option<impl Iterator>` into `impl Iterator<impl Iterator>`. Then `flatten()` steps in to remove one level of nesting.

In your code, which currently looks like this:

```
match read_dir {
    Ok(read_dir) => read_dir.filter_map(...),
    Err(_) => // ?? not sure what to do here
}
```

...you'd change it to something like:

```
match read_dir {
    Ok(read_dir) => Some(read_dir.filter_map(...)),
    Err(_) => None,
}.into_iter().flatten()
```

But `Result` already has a method called `ok()` that converts `Ok(x)` to `Some(x)` and `Err(_)` to `None`, so you can use it. Combined with `.map()` you can elinimate the explicit `match()`, resulting in something like:

```
read_dir
    .ok()
    .map(|read_dir| read_dir.filter_map(...))
    .flatten()
```

While working on this you will encounter further borrow checking issues, as your iterator hands out `&'a str`, where the `'a` namespace doesn't come from any input parameters (which is a hint that it won't compile). As others explained, you will need to hand out owned types such as `PathBuf`. Also, you'll need to convert `excluding` to something like `OsStr` to be able to compare paths provided by dir entries against it.

Here is an implementation that compiles:

```
fn dir_contents_excluding<'a>(
    dir: &Path,
    excluding: &'a str,
) -> impl Iterator<Item = PathBuf> + 'a {
    let read_dir = fs::read_dir(dir);
    let excluding = OsStr::new(excluding);
    read_dir
        .ok()
        .map(move |read_dir| {
            read_dir.filter_map(move |entry| {
                let p = entry.unwrap().path();
                if p != excluding {
                    Some(p)
                } else {
                    None
                }
            })
        })
        .into_iter()
        .flatten()
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=7c9cbb711d4fdd01353b46bec8c94687)

Answer (score -2):

First; read_dir returns a `Result<ReadDir>`. For example, the directory may not exists. The idiomatic way of handling that error is by having `dir_contents_excluding` return a `Result<..., io::Error>` as well. Then you can invoke read_dir like so:

```rust
let read_dir = fs::read_dir(dir)?;
```

The question mark makes sure any error is immediately returned, yielding you the actual `Ok(...)` result only. This is a [ReadDir](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/fs/struct.ReadDir.html) struct. This struct is an iterator yielding `io::Result<DirEntry>`, where DirEntry represents a on of the items in the directory.

Secondly; the iterator has `Item = Result<...>` because iterating through a directory can fail due to IO errors (directory deleted for example). Depending on the type of application, it could be acceptable to panic on such an error so that you can make your function interface more simple. I would not recommend silently ignoring (by filtering) the errors. This yields:

```rust
    let iter = read_dir.filter_map(|maybe_entry| {
      match maybe_entry {
          Ok(entry) => Some(...),
          Err(err) => panic!("Error in dir_contents: {err}")
      }  
    });
```

Lastly, you need to implement the filtering and decide on the return type. I would recommend getting rid of lifetime requirements by copying any references into local variables. Local variables can be `move`ed into the closure. Also, return PathBuf instead of `&str`. This becomes

```rust
use std::fs;
use std::path::{Path, PathBuf};
use std::io::Result;

fn dir_contents_excluding(dir: &Path, excluding: &str) -> Result<impl Iterator<Item = PathBuf>> {
    let read_dir = fs::read_dir(dir)?;
    let exclude = excluding.to_string();

    let iter = read_dir.filter_map(move |maybe_entry| {
      match maybe_entry {
          Ok(entry) => Some(entry.path()), // <-- replace with exclude logic
          Err(err) => panic!("Error in dir_contents: {err}")
      }  
    });
    Ok(iter)
}

fn main() {
    let dir = Path::new("./my_dir");
    for file in dir_contents_excluding(dir, "bar.txt").unwrap() {
        println!("{:?}", file);
    }
}
```

The only thing left is to check the `entry` with `exclude`. Return None if it is excluded, `Some(entry.path())` otherwise.